# How to handle returned data from http request

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am new to Angular.io and I have problems with handling with responses from http requests.
I am trying to make simple login component.

I wrote simple service :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private url ='http://localhost:3000/user/1';
  constructor(private http: Http){}
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  user : User;
  errorMessage:any;


  login(username:string, password:string) {
 this.getUser(username, password).subscribe((user)=>{
    if(user.login===username && password===user.password){
      this.isLoggedIn=true;
    }
 })
}

  logout(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }

  getUser(username:string, password:string): Observable<User>{
       return (this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError))

    }

    private extractData(res: Response){
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

and login component that calls this service:

```
  public Dologin() {
    this.message = 'Trying to log in ...';

  this.authService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
  .subscribe(() => {
  this.setMessage();
  if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {

    let redirect = '/main';

    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      preserveQueryParams: true,
      preserveFragment: true
    };

    // Redirect the user
    this.router.navigate([redirect], navigationExtras);
  }
});
 }
```

As You can see I am already consuming Observable on auth service because I need to check login, password. How modify now my Dologin method to call login wait for query to end? Like subscribe but there is no Observable anymore

Comment: What should your login api suuposeto return on valid/invalid credentials ? basis of that you can set the flag

Comment: I modified my question.  If credential are valid then isLoggedIn is set to true. If not then its left on default ( false)

Comment: Technically this is wrong you cant compare user and pass on frontend

Comment: It doesn't matter in my case. Assume that GetUser returns 1 if valid and 0 if not valid. Then In 'login' i will consume that observable to check this if this is 1 or 0.  and the problem is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use a class named `User` (I've got an error on the login field). Rename it with `MyUser` for example.

You need to use `map` instead of `subscribe` in the login function and return an `Observable<MyUser>` :

```
login(username:string, password:string) : Observable<MyUser> {
    return this.getUser(username, password).map(user => {
        if(user.login===username && password===user.password){
            this.isLoggedIn=true;
        }
        return user;
    });
}

getUser(username:string, password:string): Observable<MyUser>{
    return (this.http.get(this.url).map((r) => {
        return r.json() as MyUser;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError))

}
```

Explanations :
In the login function, you define the actions that you want to chain but these actions aren't executed yet. The chain will be executed when `subscribe()` is called.

First, you get the user (http.get) and then you check the login/password.
Then, you call `subscribe()` only once.